# Convert A Time To A Specific Time Zone

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I am learning how the C# TimeZone functions work, and am struggling on how to convert a time to a designated TimeZone.  For example, let's take the procedure below where I pass in a TimeZone and a time - how could I convert that time to the passed in TimeZone?

```
string proceduredatetime = "01/11/2017 10:17:34 AM"
string tz = "P";
string convertedDT;

convertedDT = ConvertToLocalTime(proceduredatetime, tz);
Console.WriteLine("Procedure Date Time: " + proceduredatetime);
Console.WriteLine("Timezone: " + tz);
Console.WriteLine("Converted Date Time: " convertedDT);

public static string ConvertToLocalTime(string proceduredatetime, string tz)
{
String lastscantimelocalformat;
string localtz;

switch (tz)
{
    case "C":
        localtz = "Central Standard Time";
        break;
    case "E":
        localtz = "Eastern Standard Time";
        break;
    case "M":
        localtz = "Mountain Standard Time";
        break;
    case "P":
        localtz = "Pacific Standard Time";
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid tz.");
        break;
}

if (localtz != null)
{
    tzInfo ltz = tzInfo.FindSystemtzById(localtz);
    //Lost on this step

}
}
```

Comment: What timezone is "01/11/2017 10:17:34 AM" in?  I can see 3 reasonable answers to that question:  1.  The computer's local timezone.  2.  UTC.  3.  Whatever it gets paired with in the call to `ConvertToLocalTime`.

Comment: That time is in the local server time.  I am wanting to convert it to the value in tz.  Does that help clarify?

Comment: If this code is running on the server, yes.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes - this code is running on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to know what timezone `proceduredatetime` is. I recommend getting UTC to start with. If `proceduredatetime` is not UTC then i'd convert it to UTC.

You can turn proceduredatetime into a DateTime object like this:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(proceduredatetime);
```

if you are looking for the current time use:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

then,

if `myDate` is UTC:

```
DateTime convertedDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeUtc(myDate, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(localtz));
```

if its not UTC, then you can try `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` instead:

```
DateTime convertedDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(myDate, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("SOURCE TIME ZONE"), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(localtz));
```

`convertedDateTime` should be a datetime converted to the specified timezone. You can then do a `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` or whatever format you want to get it back to a string.

Comment: Just use DateTimeOffset.